# Error: Cannot read config file: X:\package.json

Tags: json, node.js, package, lint, eslint

I am using eslint with VS Code. The configuration for eslint could be found [here](https://gist.github.com/cletusw/e01a85e399ab563b1236).

My dev environment uses ESLint v3.10.2, Node.js v5.4.1, npm v3.3.12 and VS Code v1.7.2.

The problem is that when i open the VS Code with a `.js` file, i could see output log as shown below,

```
[Info  - 11:36:58 AM] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 11:37:00 AM] ESLint library loaded from: X:\path-to-source\Source\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
[Error - 11:37:03 AM] Cannot read config file: X:\package.json Error: Cannot read config file: X:\package.json Error: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 9
```

The eslint server is able to run but it could not read the `package.json` file from the current root folder. Instead it tries to load the `package.json` from root of the drive i.e `X:`

To make sure that the issue is not with VS Code plugin, i tried to lint the files with eslint CLI but failed with the same error.

```
$ eslint app/**
Cannot read config file: X:\package.json
Error: Cannot read config file: X:\package.json
Error: Unexpected token :
SyntaxError: Cannot read config file: X:\package.json
Error: Cannot read config file: X:\package.json
Error: Unexpected token :
    at Object.parse (native)
    at loadJSONConfigFile (A:\use folder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eslint\lib\config\config-file.js:120:21)
```

I could not figure out why eslint is looking for `package.json` at root of the drive `X:` instead of the current working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESLint uses a [configuration cascade](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy), meaning it traverses up as far as it can, merging configs as it goes. In your working directory's `.eslintrc`, you can add `{ "root": true }` to limit ESLint's config search to within your working directory.